# How to save a new URL with at godbolt.org?

Tags: user-interface

I am expecting a similar behaviour as JSfiddle.net and other classic showcasing sites...  So I need to edit and "save as new URL", but the save is not working with this option, and there are no obvious interface to do it.

---

Example:

I need to add two lines at https://godbolt.org/z/Ys_RCz  ...

```
int64_t is3(int64_t checkMe){return checkMe==3;}

int64_t is9(int64_t checkMe){return checkMe==0x90000000LL;}
```

Them "save" as a new URL to use here, to show the results to other people... **How to "save" the new URL?**

Comment: there is a 'Share' option on the right that generates an URL.

Comment: Hi @PawełŁukasik, thanks! It is a so trivial question, sorry.. You can post an answer or I can delete... What you prefer?

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a 'Share' option on the top right corner that generates a new URL.

[image]

There are few options for the sharing link available.